# How to include selectOption field for aura datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable, selectoption

I am trying to build a datatable with selectOption as one of the table columns. i.e.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Booking Name', fieldName: 'bookingName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Cancellation Date', fieldName: 'canReqDate', type: 'date'},
        {label: 'Reason', fieldName: 'canReason', type: 'option'},
    ]);
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    ...
},
```

I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm) but selectoption/option isn't one of them. is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at LWC version of datadable ([lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)). There is a possibility to create custom data types using LWC and that may solve your issue.